# Kubernetes 1.6 install issue with centos 7

Tags: kubernetes, centos7

I am trying to install kubernetes on my centos 7 machine. added below yum repo. when I install the package its giving version 1.6 & 1.5.

unable to install the kubernetes package in my master server.

```
[root@centos-master yum.repos.d]# yum list|grep kube
kubeadm.x86_64                             1.6.2-0                     @kubernetes
kubectl.x86_64                             1.6.2-0                     @kubernetes
kubelet.x86_64                             1.6.2-0                     @kubernetes
kubernetes-cni.x86_64                      0.5.1-0                     @kubernetes
cockpit-kubernetes.x86_64                  135-4.el7.centos            extras
kubernetes.x86_64                          1.5.2-0.5.gita552679.el7    extras
kubernetes-client.x86_64                   1.5.2-0.5.gita552679.el7    extras
kubernetes-master.x86_64                   1.5.2-0.5.gita552679.el7    extras
kubernetes-node.x86_64                     1.5.2-0.5.gita552679.el7    extras
kubernetes-unit-test.x86_64                1.5.2-0.5.gita552679.el7    extras
rkt.x86_64                                 1.25.0-1                    kubernetes
```

here is the report for api server.

```
# yum provides kube-apiserver
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.dallas-tx.riverfrontnetworks.com
 * extras: cosmos.illinois.edu
 * updates: mirror.solarvps.com
kubernetes-master-1.3.0-0.3.git86dc49a.el7.x86_64 : Kubernetes services for master host
Repo        : extras
Matched from:
Filename    : /usr/bin/kube-apiserver



kubernetes-master-1.4.0-0.1.git87d9d8d.el7.x86_64 : Kubernetes services for master host
Repo        : extras
Matched from:
Filename    : /usr/bin/kube-apiserver



kubernetes-master-1.5.2-0.2.gitc55cf2b.el7.x86_64 : Kubernetes services for master host
Repo        : extras
Matched from:
Filename    : /usr/bin/kube-apiserver



kubernetes-master-1.5.2-0.5.gita552679.el7.x86_64 : Kubernetes services for master host
Repo        : extras
Matched from:
Filename    : /usr/bin/kube-apiserver
```

repo added.

```
# cat kubernetes.repo
[kubernetes]
name=Kubernetes
baseurl=http://yum.kubernetes.io/repos/kubernetes-el7-x86_64
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
repo_gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=https://packages.cloud.google.com/yum/doc/yum-key.gpg
        https://packages.cloud.google.com/yum/doc/rpm-package-key.gpg
```

how can I install 1.6 version. here is the error message.

```
 yum install kubernetes
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.dallas-tx.riverfrontnetworks.com
 * extras: cosmos.illinois.edu
 * updates: mirror.solarvps.com
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package kubernetes.x86_64 0:1.5.2-0.5.gita552679.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: kubernetes-node = 1.5.2-0.5.gita552679.el7 for package: kubernetes-1.5.2-0.5.gita552679.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: kubernetes-master = 1.5.2-0.5.gita552679.el7 for package: kubernetes-1.5.2-0.5.gita552679.el7.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package kubernetes-master.x86_64 0:1.5.2-0.5.gita552679.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: kubernetes-client = 1.5.2-0.5.gita552679.el7 for package: kubernetes-master-1.5.2-0.5.gita552679.el7.x86_64
---> Package kubernetes-node.x86_64 0:1.5.2-0.5.gita552679.el7 will be installed
--> Running transaction check
---> Package kubernetes-client.x86_64 0:1.5.2-0.5.gita552679.el7 will be installed
--> Finished Dependency Resolution

Dependencies Resolved

===============================================================================================================================================================================================================
 Package                                              Arch                                      Version                                                        Repository                                 Size
===============================================================================================================================================================================================================
Installing:
 kubernetes                                           x86_64                                    1.5.2-0.5.gita552679.el7                                       extras                                     36 k
Installing for dependencies:
 kubernetes-client                                    x86_64                                    1.5.2-0.5.gita552679.el7                                       extras                                     14 M
 kubernetes-master                                    x86_64                                    1.5.2-0.5.gita552679.el7                                       extras                                     25 M
 kubernetes-node                                      x86_64                                    1.5.2-0.5.gita552679.el7                                       extras                                     14 M

Transaction Summary
===============================================================================================================================================================================================================
Install  1 Package (+3 Dependent packages)

Total download size: 53 M
Installed size: 302 M
Is this ok [y/d/N]: y
Downloading packages:
(1/4): kubernetes-1.5.2-0.5.gita552679.el7.x86_64.rpm                                                                                                                                   |  36 kB  00:00:00
(2/4): kubernetes-client-1.5.2-0.5.gita552679.el7.x86_64.rpm                                                                                                                            |  14 MB  00:00:07
(3/4): kubernetes-master-1.5.2-0.5.gita552679.el7.x86_64.rpm                                                                                                                            |  25 MB  00:00:12
(4/4): kubernetes-node-1.5.2-0.5.gita552679.el7.x86_64.rpm                                                                                                                              |  14 MB  00:00:06
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total                                                                                                                                                                          3.8 MB/s |  53 MB  00:00:14
Running transaction check
Running transaction test


Transaction check error:
  file /usr/bin/kubectl from install of kubernetes-client-1.5.2-0.5.gita552679.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package kubectl-1.6.2-0.x86_64
  file /usr/bin/kubelet from install of kubernetes-node-1.5.2-0.5.gita552679.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package kubelet-1.6.2-0.x86_64
```

Thanks
SR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For kubernetes 1.6.2 we need only these rpms. when we run the

> kubeadm init

command. it starts other process automatically.

```
# rpm -qa |grep kube
kubelet-1.6.2-0.x86_64
kubeadm-1.6.2-0.x86_64
kubernetes-cni-0.5.1-0.x86_64
kubectl-1.6.2-0.x86_64
```

More info here:

https://kubernetes.io/docs/getting-started-guides/kubeadm/

Thanks
SR

Comment: Kubeadm is not recommended to be used in prod. Were you able to figure out how to install Kubernetes 1.6 on Centos 7 with the standalone components kubernetes-master.x86_64 , kubernetes-client.x86_64 ? I still see the repos contains only 1.5.2, not even 1.5.3

Comment: I used only kubeadm to build my cluster. contos report not updated for kubernetes, add this repo.  it has latest rpm https://packages.cloud.google.com/yum/repos/kubernetes-el7-x86_64/repodata/filelists.xml

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have installed kubelet & kubectl 1.5.2 already.You can uninstall 1.5.2 and retry the install of 1.6.x.

Yum normally installs the latest version of a package, regardless of which repository provides it.In this case it has a conflicting package already installed.

Edit: Removed the Centos extras reference as it was out of context.

Comment: I disabled the extra repo. looks kubernetes binary rpm not in this rpm repo. https://packages.cloud.google.com/yum/repos/kubernetes-el7-x86_64/repodata/filelists.xml